# Cordova-2.1.0 Couldn't load CordovaLib.xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4.5

I have recently upgraded to cordova 2.1.0 and previously each Xcode project referenced its own cordovalib folder.
I thought I understood that if you want an Xcode to use a cordovalib on its own and not share it with any other projects, then you can run

```
./update_cordova_subproject 
in
Cordova-2.1.0/lib/ios/bin
```

and that if you don't run the update script with its parameters then you can share the CordovaLib.xcodeproj file across many projects. However if I open two Xcode projects that reference the same Xcode project I get this error:

```
Cordova-2.1.0-global/lib/ios/CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj Couldn't load CordovaLib.xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace
```

and if I try opening the CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj file I get this error:

```
The file couldn’t be opened.
```

However all projects run without any problems.

Quitting xcode and reopening the project without any others that reference the same cordovalib  open removes the error.

Does this mean that:

1. I cannot share a CordovaLib.xcodeproj file across many projects and each project has to have its own cordovalib that it references, otherwise I could run into serious problems in the long run? Or
2. I can share a cordovalib across many projects but can only have one Xcode project open at any point in time and that I will not run into any serious problems in the near future?
3. Is there something I am overlooking?

I have tried googling the problem but most of the questions refer to previous versions of cordova whereby the method of referencing the CordovaLib was different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the subproject, but you can only have it open in one app at a time.

Not a problem if you only work on one thing at a time like most people, but since my current preferred development setup involves 18 desktops and never closing anything, I work around it with git submodules - each app gets its own fully independent copy of Cordova without actually keeping a separate copy in source control.